# Upgrade gradle from 3.4 to 3.5 throws "error: cannot find symbol class" and "error: package ... does not exist" in generated DataBindingClasses

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

we upgrade gradle from 3.4.0 to 3.5.2 and reimported the wrapper with `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip`. Unfortunately Android Studio is throwing the following erros multiple times:

```
error: cannot find symbol class UI  
error: package MyPackage does not exist
```

in my DatabindingClasses `app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug/out/`

The missing symbols and packages are all related to mine. So the imports of the generated DataBindingClass looks like this:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding;
import com.mypackage.mypackage.R;
import com.mypackage.mypackage.UI;
import java.lang.Deprecated;
import java.lang.Object;
```

After the upgrade I cleaned the project, invalidated the cache, deleted the generated build folder and restarted android studio but without success.

Is there something new in 3.5 which is missed? I read through their release notes and can't find anything.

Comment: Did you try gradle sync again?

Comment: Yes. I ran it also multiple times via the terminal besides the android studio ui